# I am creating a plot using ggplot with year on the x axis and fill by position

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to see what position showed up in what year. Some ids might not contain certain positions.

```
ID   YEAR  POS
    144 2017   10
    144 2017  12
    144 2017  18
    144 2017  15
    144 2017  163
    144 2017 200
    AB01 2018  10
    AB01 2018 15
    AB01 2018 18
```

This is what I have tried

```
ggplot(data1) + geom_bar(aes(ID, fill=POS)) + facet_wrap(~ data1$YEAR) + labs(x="Year", y= "Number ", fill = "position", Title= "Pos plot") + theme(text = element_text(size = 15, color = "Black"))
```

Comment: Do you have an example of your expected plot that you are looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you're looking for?

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data1, aes(x = ID, y=1, fill = as.factor(POS))) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "stack") + 
  facet_wrap(~ data1$YEAR) + 
  labs(x="Year", y= "Number ", fill = "position", Title= "Pos plot") + 
  theme(text = element_text(size = 15, color = "Black"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Ian Campbell. I added facet_wrap(~ data1$Year, ncol=1, scale="free") to remove IDs that are not present in that year. I wonder if there is a way to include missing values in the plot too. Example plot all 6 positions for AB01 and use a white color for missing data.

Comment: I'm not totally sure what you mean. Perhaps opening a new question and mock up what you're looking for in mspaint, preview, or gimp.